# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'master-system/update-system'

Tags: angular, authentication

I am unable to figure out where and what am i missing. I am trying to create authorization for child routes. And if the user is --> Admin only he can view the url's and if the user is ---> notAdmin , then only he cannot view certain urls'.I have done one authorization, that in login.component.ts, i check if the user is Admin or not and store it in localStorage, for further access, but it doesn't work,when i separately put the url and access the page.

Eg. i am unable to authorize the access of this particular url for --> notAdmin

http://localhost:4200/#/master-system/add-group

Error i get is -

```
 Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'master-system/update-system'
```

P.S : Does the update-user component has to be inside master-user component compulsorily?
code

**routing-module.ts**

```
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
    path: '',
    data: {
        title: 'Master System'
       },
    children: [
        {
            path: 'master-systems',
            component: MasterSystemsComponent,
            canActivateChild:[AuthGuard],
            data: {
                title: 'Master Systems'
            },
            children:[
                {
                    path: 'add-system',
                    component: AddSystemComponent,

                    data: {
                        title: 'Add'
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: 'update-system',
                    component: UpdateSystemComponent,

                    data: {
                        title: 'Update'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'master-interface',
            component: MasterInterfaceComponent,
            canActivateChild:[AuthGuard],
            data: {
                title: 'Master Interface'
            },
            children:[{
                path: 'add-interface',
                component: AddInterfaceComponent,

                data: {
                    title: 'Add'
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'update-interface',
                component: UpdateInterfaceComponent,

                data: {
                    title: 'Update'
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            path: 'master-user',
            component: MasterUserComponent,
            canActivateChild:[AuthGuard],
            data: {
                title: 'Master User'
            },
            children:[
                {
                    path: 'add-user',
                    component: AddUserComponent,

                    data: {
                        title: 'Add'
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: 'update-user',
                    component: UpdateUserComponent,


                    data: {
                        title: 'Update',
                        expectedRole: '18'
                    },

                },
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'master-group',
            component: GroupComponent,
            canActivateChild:[AuthGuard],
            data: {
                title: 'Master Group'
            },
            children:[
                {
                    path: 'add-group',
                    component: AddGroupComponent,

                    data: {
                        title: 'Add',
                        expectedRole: '18'
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: 'update-group',
                    component: UpdateGroupComponent,
                    data: {
                        title: 'Update'
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'master-role',
            component: RoleComponent,
            canActivateChild:[AuthGuard],
            data: {
                title: 'Master Role'
            },
            children:[ {
                path: 'add-role',
                component: AddRoleComponent,
                data: {
                    title: 'Add'
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'update-role',
                component: UpdateRoleComponent,
                data: {
                    title: 'Update'
                }
            },
        ]
         },  ]

        }
       ];

  @NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class MasterSystemRoutingModule { }
```

**authGuard.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot,     RouterStateSnapshot,       
  CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';


   @Injectable()

    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivateChild, CanActivate {
      expectedRole: any;
      accessId:boolean=false;
       constructor(private router: Router) { }

   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)          
     {
    if (localStorage.getItem('CurrentUser')){

        console.log("IN AUTHGUARD", localStorage.getItem('CurrentUser'));
        console.log("inside CanActivate - true  ")
        return true;

    }
    else {

        this.router.navigate(['/pages/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl:
     state.url } });
        console.log("inside CanActivate - false -  
     this.router.navigate(['/pages/login'] ")
        return false;
        }
     }

   canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:     
   RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.expectedRole = route.data;
    console.log("AAAAAA ", this.expectedRole);


        if ( localStorage.getItem('Access') == "18") {

              this.accessId = true;
              localStorage.setItem('accessId',    
      JSON.stringify(this.accessId));
              var output = localStorage.getItem('accessId');
              console.log("localStorage.getItem('accessId') = ",output)

             return true;
        }

        else 

        {
            this.router.navigate(['/pages/login'], { queryParams: {      
     returnUrl: state.url } });


            return false;         
           }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

path: '**master-systems**', != '**master-system**/update-system'

Maybe it's just a typo?